# Rename Enum in xsd with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I would like to know if it is possible and if so how to rename an Enum in an xsd file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
    targetNamespace="blabla:xsd:3" 
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="3.1">
    
    <xsd:simpleType name="IrrelevantEnumerationType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="IRRELEVANT1"/>
            ...
            ...
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="RelevantEnumerationType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="RE_LEVANT"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="IRRELEVANT2"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The generated Java code looks like this

```
@XmlType(name = "RelevantEnumerationType", namespace = "blabla:xsd:3")
@XmlEnum
public enum RelevantEnumerationType {

    RE_LEVANT,
    IRRELEVANT2;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static RelevantEnumerationType fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }

}
```

The jaxb file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xjc= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:simple/>
        </jxb:globalBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I have remove most irrelevant information and only kept the original structure.

As you can see I have an Enum that is generated as RE_LEVANT and I would like to be remove the underscore when generating to Java code.

So the result should be RELEVANT instead.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='RelevantEnumerationType']//*//xs:enumeration[@value='RE_LEVANT']">
            <typesafeEnumMember name="RELEVANT"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

You can read more about bindings in documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html

Comment: This almost works. I accepted the answer a little too quickly. The enum generated with your bindnings looks like this now: @XmlEnumValue("RE_LEVANT") RELEVANT("RE_LEVANT") How to also have to value be RELEVANT and not RE_LEVANT?

Comment: Not sure that you can